# cat file : prints prior to "user :/" prompt

Tags: bash, text-processing, command-line, prompt, cat

file contains just 1 line:

```
aaa
```

when I run "cat file" it mixes to username

```
user /dir : cat file
aaauser /dir :
```

What could be the problem ?

Extra Info:

perhaps this is not properly set in bashrc ? ?

```
PS1='\u \W : '
```

UPDATE:

shouldnt there be a solution other than including a newline to the file ?

Why would there be no care for the elements that can distort the command line prompt ? ( by not having a new line )

Comment: Perhaps `file` is missing its terminating newline character - check with `xxd file` or similar

Comment: The file does not contain a line, but only three characters. There nneds to be a line break (`\n`) at the end.

Comment: even if there is no "\n", why should the terminal command line be distorted ? there is no care for this?

Comment: The file contains no final newline. `cat` will not add one if there isn't one there. If it did so, it would not faithfully reproduce the file contents. You will also notice that the file contains zero lines (check with `wc -l file`). A line ends with a newline. The terminal prompt is not "distorted". It is simply ouputted at the end of the output from the previous command, as always.

Comment: You could adjust your shell prompt (`PS1`) to start on a fresh line (`\n`), or to force a return to the beginning of the current line (`\r`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file does not have a newline at the end. As a result the shell prompt is just put right on the end. You could fix that by adding it.

```
printf '\n' >> file
```

You can recreate this issue by creating a file without a newline at the end. (The `-n` flag tells echo to not add a newline at the end.)

```
[zbrady@server ~]$ printf 'test' > testfile
[zbrady@server ~]$ cat testfile
test[zbrady@server ~]$
[zbrady@server ~]$ printf '\n' >> testfile
[zbrady@server ~]$ cat testfile
test
[zbrady@server ~]$
```

Comment: Or you could use `printf` which *only* adds newlines if explicitly asked. :)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling valid point. I was raised on echo so it's just habit.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, your file has an incomplete final line (the last
character is not a newline).

Regarding your updated question "why would there be no care for the
elements that can distort the command line prompt?", well, the cat
command indeed does not know or generally care about terminals; it
just copies its input files to its standard output.

If you want to avoid this kind of issue, you can use a proper pager,
such as less, instead.